# sqlite inserting blob - bind or column index out of range

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a binary file to sqlite database. I'm getting "bind or column index out of range" error. I've no idea why I'm getting that error, everything seems to be in order. I've marked the location of error with a comment. I've double checked that the file exists and it's size is correct.

```
private void InsertBlob(uint PID, uint MID, int CR, int CG, int CB){
    ifstream file("my_file.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0, ifstream::end);
    streampos size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0);

    //read file to buffer
    char* buffer = new char[size];
    file.read(buffer, size);

    //C++ string build, MBinary is blob others are Integers
    string Command = "BEGIN; INSERT INTO Dat (PID,MID,CID_R,CID_G,CID_B,MBinary) VALUES (" + to_string(PID) + "," + to_string(MID) + "," + to_string(CR) + "," + to_string(CG) + "," + to_string(CB) + ",?);COMMIT;";

    //convert string to char
    char c_style_string[1024];
    strncpy(c_style_string, Command.c_str(), sizeof(c_style_string));
    c_style_string[sizeof(c_style_string) - 1] = 0;

    int rc;

    sqlite3_open("AnalysisDatabase.db3", &db);
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,c_style_string,-1, &stmt, NULL);

    **//following line throws the error: bind or column index out of range**
    rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, buffer, size, SQLITE_STATIC);

    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding to the statement `BEGIN`, which obviously has no placeholders. You need to use multiple statements. The last argument to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` sets a pointer to the next statement after the semicolon.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN", NULL, NULL, NULL);

char const* const command = "INSERT INTO Dat (PID, MID, CID_R, CID_G, CID_B, MBinary)"
                            " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

sqlite3_open("AnalysisDatabase.db3", &db);
sqlite3_stmt* stmt = NULL;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, command, -1, &stmt, NULL);

// Note: you're not handling rc. Also, why were you concatenating strings
// instead of binding params, like you were already doing for the blob?
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, PID);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, MID);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, CT);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 4, CG);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 5, CB);
rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 6, buffer, size, SQLITE_STATIC);

rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Edit: you're also not `delete`ing `buffer` in your original code. You need to start using RAII to manage your resources.

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.