# Binding an array to a blob via a prepared statement, inside a transaction

Tags: sqlite

I build an SQL statement like this:

```
"BEGIN TRANSACTION; INSERT OR IGNORE INTO test_table(id,store,insert_datetime) VALUES('abcde', ?, datetime('now')); END TRANSACTION;"
```

Then I call:

```
sqlite3_stmt* prepared_statement;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, stmt, -1, &prepared_statement, 0);
```

which is okay, followed by:

```
int index = 1;
sqlite3_bind_blob(prepared_statement, index, buffer, (int)buffer_len, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

and `sqlite3_bind_blob(...)` fails with "SQLite error (25) column index out of range"

If I remove the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `END TRANSACTION` from my statement, and just bracket the whole code block with them, it works.  Does that mean I cannot prepare a statement like I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, after spending all day on this, I found the answer shortly after I posted - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34179660/3915384

A real shame as I like having a function that wraps a statement in a begin/end but it seems like that is not possible.

Edit: Later, I also discovered autocommit mode which seems to be enabled by default so I think all of the begin/end transactions is not required at all.